# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, webpack

al tratar de replicar un ejemplo de configurar un entorno para trabajar con `React` y `Node`, me aparece un error, dando a entender como si no estuviera el `loader` respectivo para cargar y transpilar los archivos.

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `babel-node src/server.js`
Live Reload listening on port 35729

app start over the port 3000
× ｢wdm｣: Hash: 523d77cec06d570174bb
Version: webpack 4.1.1
Time: 1211ms
Built at: 2018-3-17 10:37:04
    Asset       Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
bundle.js  752 bytes       0  main
Entrypoint main = bundle.js
   [0] ./src/client/index.jsx 208 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for this environment.

ERROR in ./src/client/index.jsx
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| const App = () => {
|     return <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>;
| };
|
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
         Asset     Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
    index.html  531 KiB       0
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
       [0] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 519 bytes {0} [built]
       [1] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
       [2] ./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js 527 KiB {0} [built]
       [3] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/client/index.html 558 bytes {0} [built]
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

#### index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
    return <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>;
};

render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

#### webpack.config.js

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import htmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import LiveReloadPlugin from 'webpack-livereload-plugin';

export default {

    entry: './src/client/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {                
                test: '/\.jsx$/',
                use:{
                    loader:'babel-loader'
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                use: ['style-loader','css-loader'],
                test: '/\.css$/'
            },
            {                
                test: '/\.scss$/',
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },

                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options:
                            {
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                    },

                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options:
                            {                                
                                sourceMap: true
                            }

                    }

                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [

        new htmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/client/index.html'
        }),

        new LiveReloadPlugin()

    ] 

};
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "reactnode",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "scaffoldproject",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/server.js"
  },
  "author": "PterPmntaM",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.10",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.6",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "webpack": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack-livereload-plugin": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  }
}
```

#### server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackConfig from '../webpack.config';

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hola Mundo React - Node");
});

app.get('/api', (rep, res) => {
    res.json({api: 'works'});
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(webpack(webpackConfig)));

app.listen(app.get('port'), () =>{
    console.log('app start over the port', app.get('port'));
});
```

#### Estructura

[image: estructura]

Comment: Hola Pedro, ¿podrías agregar el contenido de `.babelrc`?

Comment: claro dame un segundo, aqui esta ```{
    "presets":[
        "env",
        "react"   
    ]
}```

Comment: Te recomendaría que pusieras de igual manera lo que se encuentra en la carpeta client, así poder replicar el error que estás obteniendo.

Comment: en la carpeta cliente, solo esta alli, el `index.html` y el `index,jsx`, no hay mas nada

Comment: Una disculpa... el archivo server, no vi bien la jerarquía de carpetas.

Comment: ya lo pongo un momento

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74678/discussion-between-pedro-miguel-pimienta-morales-and-jesus-a-meza-g).

Comment: si puedes entrar aqui seria mejor, [chat privado](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74678/discussion-between-pedro-miguel-pimienta-morales-and-jesus-a-meza-g)